# OpenXML SDK C++ Examples

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, openxml-sdk

HI,

I'm trying to create a word document in C++ using OpenXML SDK,
I'm facing problems in adding references and using namespace as most of the examples in the web are given based on C#.

1.How do I add references to project and also use namespaces(Ex - using namespace    System.Xml;) in the code

Also please suggest any C++ examples links for OpenXML SDK.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know of any for the SDK, but if you're looking for C++ in .NET and working with Open XML (`System.IO.Packaging`, etc.), grab the C++/CLI [samples](http://openxmldeveloper.org/files/1956/download.aspx) and [lab](http://openxmldeveloper.org/files/1945/download.aspx) off of the [Open XML Developer workshop content page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dmahugh/archive/2007/08/10/developer-workshop-content.aspx). In fact, all the other stuff there is also very helpful in working with Open XML.

Answer (score 1):

C++ uses static objects, hence to interact with .netframework you must use managed objects. C++/CLI is the best one for this business. Where you integrate common language infrastructure with C++. 
Check the below link..

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/quickcppcli.aspx