# OpenXML SDK -Converting C# to C++/CLI

Tags: c#, visual-c++, c++-cli, openxml-sdk

I've got C# code for creating a document, I want to write the same in C++/CLI.

```
private void HelloWorld(string documentFileName) 
{
    // Create a Wordprocessing document. 
    using (WordprocessingDocument myDoc =
           WordprocessingDocument.Create(documentFileName, 
               WordprocessingDocumentType.Document)) 
    { 
        // Add a new main document part. 
        MainDocumentPart mainPart = myDoc.AddMainDocumentPart(); 
        //Create Document tree for simple document. 
        mainPart.Document = new Document(); 
        //Create Body (this element contains
        //other elements that we want to include 
        Body body = new Body(); 
        //Create paragraph 
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(); 
        Run run_paragraph = new Run(); 
        // we want to put that text into the output document 
        Text text_paragraph = new Text("Hello World!"); 
        //Append elements appropriately. 
        run_paragraph.Append(text_paragraph); 
        paragraph.Append(run_paragraph); 
        body.Append(paragraph); 
        mainPart.Document.Append(body); 
        // Save changes to the main document part. 
        mainPart.Document.Save(); 
    } 
}
```

Also please suggest me any links where I can find C++/CLI example for OpenXML SDK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a direct translation:

```
private:
    void HelloWorld(String^ documentFileName)
    {
        msclr::auto_handle<WordprocessingDocument> myDoc(
            WordprocessingDocument::Create(
                documentFileName, WordprocessingDocumentType::Document
            )
        );
        MainDocumentPart^ mainPart = myDoc->AddMainDocumentPart();
        mainPart->Document = gcnew Document;
        Body^ body = gcnew Body;
        Paragraph^ paragraph = gcnew Paragraph;
        Run^ run_paragraph = gcnew Run;
        Text^ text_paragraph = gcnew Text(L"Hello World!");
        run_paragraph->Append(text_paragraph);
        paragraph->Append(run_paragraph);
        body->Append(paragraph);
        mainPart->Document->Append(body);
        mainPart->Document->Save();
    }
```

`msclr::auto_handle<>` should generally be considered more idiomatic than `try..finally`, just as `std::shared_ptr<>` and `std::unique_ptr<>` are in C++.

Comment: @ildjarn -I'm getting the below error the above code is compiled --

 error C2872: 'Text' : ambiguous symbol could be 'System::Text'

Comment: @Greenhorn : Get rid of `using namespace System;` or fully qualify `Text` (or create a local `typedef` for the fully-qualified `Text` and use that instead); I don't know what namespace the objects you're working with here are in, so I don't know how to fully qualify them for you to give a concrete solution for that error.

Comment: @ildjarn can you please suggest me any links where I can find C++/CLI example or tutorails on openXML SDK

Comment: @Greenhorn : I've never used OpenXML, I don't know anything about it. Sorry.

Comment: @ildjarn Can you please help me with this one..
 
mainPart->Document->Append(body); -- I'm facing problem with this line of code  mainPart->Document-> is not being recognized is there any alternative for this.

Answer (score 2):

I take it you have tried something? I don't have access to a compiler

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI should get you started.

If you wonder about translating the `using` construct (good question, had you asked it!), I suggest something along the following lines (note the `try {} finally { delete ... }` idom)

```
private:

void HelloWorld(String^ documentFileName) 
{ 
    // Create a Wordprocessing document. 
    WordprocessingDocument ^myDoc = WordprocessingDocument::Create(documentFileName, WordprocessingDocumentType::Document);
    try
    {
        // Add a new main document part. 
        MainDocumentPart mainPart = myDoc::AddMainDocumentPart(); 
        //Create Document tree for simple document. 
        mainPart->Document = gcnew Document(); 
        //Create Body (this element contains
        //other elements that we want to include 
        Body body = gcnew Body(); 
        //Create paragraph 
        Paragraph paragraph = gcnew Paragraph(); 
        Run run_paragraph = gcnew Run(); 
        // we want to put that text into the output document 
        Text text_paragraph = gcnew Text("Hello World!"); 
        //Append elements appropriately. 
        run_paragraph->Append(text_paragraph); 
        paragraph->Append(run_paragraph); 
        body->Append(paragraph); 
        mainPart->Document->Append(body); 
        // Save changes to the main document part. 
        mainPart->Document->Save(); 
    } finally
    {
        delete myDoc;
    }   
}
```

I want to repeat I have no compiler available at the moment, so it may be rough around the edges, but should provide some information nonetheless

Comment: please use RAII instead of try - finally.

Comment: @Tobias: you are missing the point. This is CLR, so RAII doesn't exist as such **for managed (gc) types**. Unless you explicitely call `delete` there is no deterministic disposal (let alone finalization) IIRC. But see [@ildjam's post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866048/openxml-sdk-converting-c-to-c-cli/5866194#5866194) for a better way

Comment: RAII absolutely exists for managed types, as long as all you expect is for `Dispose` to be called on the object rather than proper deterministic finalization. The fact that `Dispose` is implicitly called on an object declared with value (stack) semantics when it goes out of scope is precisely what makes `msclr::auto_handle<>` useful in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

[OpenXML SDK C++ Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855399/openxml-sdk-c-examples)

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is basically the same. "new" needs to be replaced by gcnew, the "." by -> (e.g. body.Append(paragraph) will be body->Append(paragraph). The tricky part will be the "using" directive. To do it the C++ way, you need some kind of smart pointer that "deletes" the object at the end of the block (with delete meaning calling the IDisposable interface) - this is called RAII.